# Why is cookie without SameSite attribute sent on cross-domain form post?

Tags: cookies, csrf, samesite

I have a page on https://dskl.net/xsrf/setcookies.php which sets a cookie with the following header:

`set-cookie: secure-cookie=secure; expires=Mon, 24-Jul-2023 11:27:06 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; domain=dskl.net; secure; HttpOnly`

If I go to this page, the value of the cookie is displayed: https://dskl.net/xsrf/getcookies.php.

But if I make a post request to that page from a form on a different domain, the cookie is also included in the request: https://manabase.com/xsrf/

Shouldn't a cookie without SameSite attribute be treated as SameSite=Lax and not have the cookie included in a cross-domain form post?

Strangely, if I make the form post a bit later, the cookie is not included. But if I delete the cookie and try again, it works again. What might be going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like the "Lax + POST" intervention, see [here](https://chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592). This is meant to support RelayState cookies during SAML logon flow even in the absence of the `SameSite` attribute, see [What is exactly RelayState parameter used in SSO (Ex. SAML)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350160/what-is-exactly-relaystate-parameter-used-in-sso-ex-saml).