# How to display an app with auth cookies inside an iframe in a secure way?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iframe, session-cookies, samesite

I have a ASP.NET web application running in IIS that handles the authentication session with cookies.

A customer wants to display this application inside an iframe of another application. However, AFAIK this would force me to set `SameSite=None` for my auth cookie, which would make it vulnerable to CRSF attacks (an also fail in any pentest audit).

Is there any way to keep my auth cookies with `SameSite=Lax` while displaying the application inside an iframe? If not, is there any secure alternative?

Comment: I don't understand your CSRF concern and don't see why `SameSite=None` should fail a pen test, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76851436/keycloak-uses-samesite-none-and-failing-in-pen-test). But cookies in an iframe (not just auth cookies) are likely to be blocked as third-party cookies.

Comment: About the CSRF concern, `SameSite=Lax` is meant as a protection against CRSF attacks, see for instance https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#samesite-cookie-attribute

About the pentest, usually companies doing security audits demand cookies to have SameSite Lax or Strict.

Comment: You won't be able to have cross-site cookies in iframes anyway once browsers start enforcing [third-party cookie blocking](https://privacysandbox.com/open-web/#the-privacy-sandbox-timeline).

Comment: This link may help you: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question after much testing and reading: It's not possible to have SameSite=Lax cookies inside an iframe, and there is no secure workaround for this.

Furthermore, as pointed out by Heiko Theißen, this will be even more impossible when browsers start enforcing [third-party cookie blocking](https://privacysandbox.com/open-web/#the-privacy-sandbox-timeline).